# Angular Material Autocomplete causing list of value to be null after selecting item

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to use Angular Material's Autocomplete form control with the DisplayWith function. I get a list of warehouses that is used for the select box. 
 But once a warehouse is selected, my list of warehouses has been wiped out. The displayWithFn cannot find the name associated with the id that was selected because my warehouse list is null.

See StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqbxbt

Where am I wiping out my list of warehouses?

**EDIT (Solution):** I have updated the StackBlitz showing the error and the solution I ended up using.  I could not use the Reactive form formControlName field with the Autocomplete.  I had to create a separate formControl, watch for changes, and then move the data to the reactive form field.  In the StackBlitz, the warehouse field shows the problem and the warehouse Stock field is the solution I ended up with for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `[displayWith]="displayWarehouseFn">` binding. It will not bind `this` unless you write it as `[displayWith]="displayWarehouseFn()">`, causing `this` to be an `MatAutocomplete` object instead of your `AppComponent`.

Comment: Thank you!  That may have helped but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It works when I change in your StackBlitz, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that did answer my question.  I will mark this as the correct answer. I guess I didn't ask my question correctly because I was hoping to have the autocomplete field hold the Id as its value and display the description to the user. I guess I will not be able to use formControlName= and will have to switch to [formControl]=  .  Thank you for your help!